# Exception error is occurring when comparing a None/null value in a list to a vectorized string

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, nlp, word2vec

```
for df in pages:
        for i, line in df.iterrows():
            fulltext.append(line['text'])
            if compare_func(word2vec('first item'), word2vec(line['text'])) > 0.90
```

Here, I am comparing two strings. If the vectorized version of those two values 'first item' and line['text'] are more than ninety percent similar then it'll be executed. But when there's a empty cell(' ') in line list, its exiting the whole function and showing Exception error.
But if there's a None value in any cell , I want it to ignore that and continue going through the items. What can be done in this case ? Any pythonic suggestions ?

Comment: you can try df['line'].dropna().iterrows()

Comment: Showing the actual exception error message you've received, with the full traceback of involved lines-of-code, is almost always necessary to help answerers deduce what's going wrong.

Comment: Separately: if the unshown code in `compare_func()` is performing a typical cosine-similarity calc on its 2 input vectors, note that the returned value **isn't** truly a "percentage similar", & the practical ranges of similarity can vary a lot based on the vector model's training parameters. So, a cutoff threshold like `0.9` should be experimentally chosen for desired results, & an alt/retrained vector set (esp with a different # of dimensions) might need a very different value, even if it still puts the same right words close to each other.